# Working with Radio Button properties in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button

In my program I have a ViewModel that alters the data in two different models. It does this through `radioButton` proxy properties. I've looked into `radioButton` commands with MVVM, and I know that they are different than other controls.

What I see happening when I debug these proxy properties is that whenever a `radioButton` is selected, the program runs through the commands of the last selected `radioButton`. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

This is an example of one of my `radioButton` proxy properties that performs a number of operations:

```
public bool myRadioButton
{
       get { return modelA.myRadioButton; }
       set
       {
           modelA.myRadioButton = value;
           NotifyPropertyChange(() => myRadioButton);

           modelA.checkBox1 = !value;
           modelA.checkBox2 = !value;
           viewModelB.modelB.label1Visibility = !value;
           viewModelB.modelB.label2Visibility = !value;
       }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to understand, what's your problem. Could you post a code sample?

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: Just imagine two radio buttons : R1 & R2.

R1 is in a selected state, R2 is not. You click on R1 so it will trigger an event because its state went from Selected to Not Selected. As R2 has its state changed too it will trigger an event from Not Selected to Selected. But the first event to be catched will be the one from R1 I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented `RadioButtonExtended` from [this blog post](http://pstaev.blogspot.com/2008/10/binding-ischecked-property-of.html). The solution works perfectly for this problem.